# How to ignore the AND field = value when the value is blank in SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I submit the price and category_id through a form and then the query shows me the results. What I have is this below.

```
$s = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["s"]);
$c = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["c"]);

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE price <= '$s' AND category_id = '$c'
```

When a user does not select any category and the value of it is blank, there is nothing displayed. How can I fix the query that if `$c` does not have any value ignore the  `AND category_id = '$c'` ?

I thought to create a second query for this purpose, but is there any other way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$s = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["s"]);
$c = (int) $_GET["c"];

$qpart = ($c > 0 ? " AND category_id = $c " : '');
$qry = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE price <= '$s' ". $qpart;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a question though. Is (int) better to be used than mysql_real_escape when c will be always an integer?

Comment: @Nikolai Yes I believe its better to use `(int)` if the value expected is always integer, cause escaping would still allow strings etc to be sent but (int) forcefully converts everything to integer, if it is an integer, perfect, if not you will get a zero.

Answer (score 2):

Like this :

```
if(isset($c)){

$cat = " AND category_id = '$c'"

}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE price <= '$s'" . $cat;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$addition = '';
if(isset($c) && !empty($c) {
  $addition = ' AND category_id = ' . $c;
}

$qry = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE price <= '$s'" . $addition;
```

Comment: This is correct because it's checking if the variable exists and it's not empty, this way you can avoid any notice.

Answer (score 0):

how about using simple logic? 
if the parameter has not been supplied it should short circuit the column check and select all rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM products 
WHERE ($s = 0    OR price <= $s) AND 
      ('$c' = '' OR category_id = '$c')
```